# Does Go allow to convert any type of data to []byte?

Tags: go

In the below code, `json.Marshal` converts any type of data to `[]byte`:

```
bolB, _ := json.Marshal(true)
intB, _ := json.Marshal(1)
fltB, _ := json.Marshal(2.34)
strB, _ := json.Marshal("gopher")

slcD := []string{"apple", "peach", "pear"}
slcB, _ := json.Marshal(slcD)

mapD := map[string]int{"apple": 5, "lettuce": 7}
mapB, _ := json.Marshal(mapD)

res1D := struct {
    Page   int
    Fruits []string
}{
    Page:   1,
    Fruits: []string{"apple", "peach", "pear"},
}
res1B, _ := json.Marshal(res1D)
```

---

But language does not allow explicit type conversion for all types of data, for example, `b := []byte(true)` does not work.

Implication, I cannot implement `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)`(io.Reader) method to stream any type of data source as `[]byte`, except string type `strBytes := []byte(myStringData.str)`

How `json.Marshal` is able to convert any type of data to `[]byte`?

Comment: You can read the [Go encode code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L28) & doc

Comment: Json marshalling is not type conversion.

Comment: @Marc In this [code](https://play.golang.org/p/nPt3ZEdCFgI), untyped constant `1` is being converted to type(slice of bytes) `[49]`. This is something similar to : `string(1) == string([]byte{1})`

Comment: No, it's being marshalled (or encoded) into json. This is a completely different format that requires encoding and decoding, **it is not type conversion**.

Comment: @Marc when you say, marshal, any types is being converted to raw string literal and then converted to slice of bytes.

Comment: @MuffinTop `json.Marshal` returns decimal text in a JSON document, yes... for example, `v := struct {Page int}{1,}; json.Marshal(v)` converts value `v` of struct type to slice of bytes(decimal text) in JSON document `[123 34 80 97 103 101 34 58 49 125]` which is nothing but UTF-8 encoded version of `{"Page":1}` ..... But am unclear about the conversion for `json.Marshal('a')`  from `'a'` to `[57 55]`. Oh... so this is not type conversion

Comment: @overexchange `'a'` is an integer constant with value 97.  The value 97 is encoded to JSON as the bytes 57 and 55.

Comment: @MuffinTop So, How to provide data to `p` in `Read(p []byte)` method of `io.Reader` that populates any source data type converted as `[]byte`? Because data source cannot always be string type something like... `type MyStringDataSource struct {  str string; readIndex int // default: 0 ;}`  that can be converted to `[]byte(str)`...

Answer (score 2):

> How json.Marshal is able to convert any type of data to []byte?

`json.Marshal` is **not** able to convert any type of data to `[]byte` as explained in the documentation of package encoding/json.

The headline question was:

> Does Go allow to convert any type of data to []byte?

The formal answer would be: Yes, e.g. via

```
func convertToBytes(interface{}) []byte {
    return nil
}
```

Albeit the conversion is not reversible which makes this conversion useless for any practical purpose.